# How to set: press and hold listener to checkbox

Tags: java, android, listener

I was looking for a listener for `checkBox` that listens for action: press and hold. I fin only `setOnClickListener(...)`. Is there any listener for that gesture?

This is my checkBox:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(rootView.getContext(), product);
```

Answer (score 1):

press and hold is the long press gesture, if I have not misunderstood you. You can try to attach `OnLongClickListener` on it, through

```
cb.setOnLongClickListener()
```